# XMLHttpRequest cannot load к laravel

Tags: json, angularjs, laravel

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://localhost:8000/api/v1/user/user_signin. Response to preflight
>   request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

Я делаю post запрос от angular к laravel серверу. Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: это как раз решается добавлением указанного заголовка в ответ сервера

Comment: У меня что-то около 50 уникальных ссылок к api.
Как добавить этот заголовок для всех сразу?

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/laravel-5-cors-headers-with-filters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Ответ от автора есть, но всё-таки..*

Более гибкое (*и более сложное*) решение: [CORS in Laravel 5](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors)

Установка:

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-cors
```

Подключение (в файл `config/app.php`, массив `providers`):

```
Barryvdh\Cors\ServiceProvider::class,
```

Публикация конфига:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Barryvdh\Cors\ServiceProvider"
// сюда: config/cors.php
```

Использование:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'cors'], function(Router $router){
    // маршруты
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ссылку на [правильное](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/laravel-5-cors-headers-with-filters) решение предоставил @Grundy , за что ему большое спасибо. Там есть разные варианты, одни работают, другие нет. Отправляю то, что работает для меня:

В файле [bootstrap/app.php] добавить после `<?php:`

```
// allow origin
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
// add any additional headers you need to support here
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type');
```